# Можно ли добавлять сторонний файл в java проект?

Tags: java, eclipse

Могу ли я добавить сторонний файл (например .wav) в свой java проект в Eclipse? Если да, то как?

Comment: Берете файл, копируете, вставляете...

Comment: А в чем вопрос?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого нужно настроить сборщик приложения. Например maven. `src/main/resources` - папка с файлами

````
...
<build>
    ...
    <resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
    </resource>
    ...
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
...
</project>```
````